# How to find every java process?

Tags: java, c, windows

Is it possible somehow to find every running `java` process? Specifically I would need the ProcessId of the Java processes.

If I install the Java Developement Kit, there is an exe called `jps.rexe`. If I run this exe it finds every running java processes and lists their ProcessID. Basically I need the same, but written in `C`. The `jps.exe` requires Java Developement Kit to be installed.

Also note there are two scenarios:
  - A `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` (there are some more) process starts the reuired process, so in this case it would be "easy" to find the java processes.
  - The second one is more complicated. An application will be started, but only some components or features requires java, and there are no `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` process running, but the application still uses the jre.

Hopefully it is clear, what I want.

Does anyone have have any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: C# sharp allows to execute powershell command then you can do "Get-Process Java*" can you do with c? it will display all java related process

Comment: Can't you run `tasklist` using stdlib's `system()` to get the list of processes that you then parse?

Comment: No, you can't possibly. Someone can rename executables and dlls so as to run Java invisibly to you.

Comment: @ASP: I could probably, but eventually it would be in powershell not in C.

Comment: @meaning-matters: of course I could, but it still wouldn't be in C. Also, if i get the list of every running process(which I could get also with Windows APIs), I still wouldn't know which one is a java process and which one isn't. That's actually my problem

Answer (score 1):

(Take this as a comment which is unfortunately to long, so I post it as an answer.) Just providing some links which I stumbled upon looking for an answer:

As using a JRE file probably means having it open, the Sysinternals tool [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) might be helpful. It seems to use the [Windows Object Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_%28Windows%29) to be able to find open files (by path fragment) and their associated processes.

The only promising [C source code](http://www.drdobbs.com/using-nts-undocumented-object-manager-in/184416468) related to Object Manager I found unfortunately seems quite outdated (1997). But at least the key function [NtQueryDirectoryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) used there still exists although it *"has no associated import library or header file"*. So it might still be possible to make use of that C code.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK in Java 8 provides several libraries for Monitoring. I've used visualvm:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/

visualvm allows us to visualise and recover information about the process ids, ammount of memory used for each process, etc. So with this tool you can find every running java process.

If you need to do some work with the process id, the next step will be how visualvm does for getting such information.

Good luck!